# Cannot Connect Mercury Test Director 8.0 sp2 to Oracle 10

Tags: testing, oracle10g, hp-quality-center

Im trying to connect Mercury Test Director 8.0 sp2 to Oracle 10g but any way i try just fails i have done loads of research and have come to the conclusion Oracle 10g isn't supported by TD 8. Never the less from previous experience there is always a way. I would any advice im a bit of a newbie when it comes to this.